# How to get a Xamarin iOS app from Visual Studio onto my iPhone?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I have Visual Studio 2015 installed on my Windows PC. On a Mac that I want to use as a build server I have Xamarin Studio installed and I have also gone through the whole [Device Provisioning](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/) process with my iPhone.

Now I would like to try run some sample app on my iPhone. I connect to the Mac by clicking the Xamarin Mac Agent icon. I plug my iPhone in my Windows PC and click 'Device' ([see print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eTOT.png)). At that moment the app builds successfully (the last line of Output window is `========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`) but I get this error: `Please select a valid device before running the application`.

So my question is: Can I get an iOS app to run from a Windows PC at all? Or would the iPhone have to be connected to the Mac, not the PC? If it is possible, what could I be doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

At the Evolve conference a couple weeks ago, Xamarin announced support for deploying to an iPhone plugged into the PC, I don't think it's available yet: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65834/ios-usb-remoting

One way to do this fairly easily is to use HockeyApp http://hockeyapp.net, you can deploy test versions of your app for up to 2 apps for free, and there is a Mac desktop app that makes uploading new versions into HockeyApp an easy process.

Comment: Good call, I just signed up because HockeyApp is also free for up to 2 apps, enough for me right now. I'm at a point where I want to invite testers and it should be interesting to integrate their crash SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I found getting the deployment to an actual device the first time quite tricky, but once it works, it's easy in the future:

- Make sure you have all your certs, profiles, app IDs, device
  registration complete in your Apple Developer account
- On your Mac, create a little Hello World in XCode(!). I found that
  it's a bit better in hand-holding to verify that everything is in
  place.
- Only when you successfully got that test app on to your device, move
  back to Xamarin/Visual Studio
- Remember that you need to also set your certificates in Visual Studio
  in your Info.plist (or your project Properties). If communication
  works correctly, you should have a drop-down item in the options.

Answer (score 0):

You should plug IPhone in MAC and then deploy button in Visual Studio will change it's name to your device name.
Also, you can use Virtual MAC. So then you can plug iPhone in Windows PC, it's will connect to your Virtual MAC too.